# Pyspark - Transpose

Tags: pyspark, transpose

In Pyspark have dataset as below

```
+-----------+-----------+                                                       
|weekend_day|totals     |
+-----------+-----------+
| 2023-02-25|  401943676|
| 2023-03-11|  410220150|
+-----------+-----------+
```

and the expected output is

```
 -----------------------------------
|        | 2023-02-25 | 2023-03-11 |
| totals | 401943676  | 410220150  |
```

pivot is not providing the result. Please advice how it can be achieved?

Please note I don't want to use Pandas

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean of `pivot` is not providing the result?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2023-02-25', 401943676), ('2023-03-11', 410220150)],
    schema=['weekend_day', 'totals']
)
df.printSchema()
df.show(3, False)
+-----------+---------+
|weekend_day|totals   |
+-----------+---------+
|2023-02-25 |401943676|
|2023-03-11 |410220150|
+-----------+---------+
```

You can use `groupBy` and `pivot` to achieve the expected output:
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

```
df.groupBy(
    func.lit('total').alias('col_name')
).pivot(
    'weekend_day'
).agg(
    func.first('totals')
).show(
    10, False
)
+--------+----------+----------+
|col_name|2023-02-25|2023-03-11|
+--------+----------+----------+
|total   |401943676 |410220150 |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same is by doing somewhat as below -

```
weekend_days = df.select("weekend_day").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

transformed_df = df.groupBy(lit("totals").alias("columnName")).agg(*[sum(when(col("weekend_day") == day, col("totals"))).alias(day) for day in weekend_days])

transformed_df.show()

+----------+----------+----------+
|columnName|2023-02-25|2023-03-11|
+----------+----------+----------+
|    totals| 401943676| 410220150|
+----------+----------+----------+
```